# having a relationship with god

Tags: tefilla

can some one answer this whats the best way to have a consistent relationship with god

Answer (score 3):

Learning Torah, doing the 613 Mitsvos, keeping Shobbos and being a good friendly person.

Comment: Why are 1, 3 and 4 not included in 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion question but regular conversations with Him are very helpful. This is the Breslov approach, and Rabbi Avigdor Miller and the Mesilas Yesharim all bring it down. But, as Rabbi Miller said, not to loud or they will take you away.

Comment: What's with all the shouting?

Comment: My keyboard is a little haywire